# How Can i get value (ID) Acc to the option i selected in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to build a section in my website with Jquery Autocomplete

```
<li> 
  <input id="tags" id="srch_term" name="srch_term" class="form-control">
</li>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var location = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: $('#hf_base_url').val() + '/ajax/all_location_processing',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',    
    headers: { 
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
    }, 
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, val) { 
        location.push({
          id: val.id,
          name:val.name
        }); 
      })
    },
    error:function() {}
  });
});
```

Here what I have done getting all locations when page loads and store the `location_id` and `location_name` in an array named `location`.

```
{ id: 24, name: "Baltimore" },
{ id: 25, name: "Brooklyn" },
{ id: 26, name: "Chicago" },
{ id: 27, name: "Cleveland" },
{ id: 28, name: "Denver" },
{ id: 29, name: "Detroit" },
{ id: 30, name: "Edison" },
{ id: 31, name: "Five Towns" },
{ id: 32, name: "Flatbush" },
{ id: 33, name: "Israel"},
{ id: 34, name: "Lakewood" },
{ id: 35, name: "Los Angeles" },
{ id: 36, name: "Miami" },
{ id: 37, name: "Monsey" },
{ id: 38, name: "Montreal" },
{ id: 39, name: "Passaic" },
{ id: 40, name: "Philadelphia" },
{ id: 41, name: "Tornoto" },
```

Now what I have do when location is selected in autocomplete then I want to get `location_id` so that I can do further tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_location_hidden" val="">
```

check this code, Hope it will help you.

```
$("#srch_term").autocomplete({
    source: url,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#id_location_hidden").val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```